# Is the Steel Defender's Force Empowered Rend affected by items that add +1 to Spell attack rolls?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, artificer, artificer-infusions

Do items that affect an Artificer's spell attack modifier also affect the Steel Defender's actions that use said spell attack modifier?

As an example, my current level 4 Artificer has

- +4 INT
- +2 Prof bonus
- +1 from an All-Purpose Tool
- +1 from the Enhanced Arcane Focus

So a +8 to spell attacks. Does this mean that Force Empowered Rend also has +8?

See **Steel Defender's Force Empowered Rend** Tasha's Cauldron of Everything (pg. 19):

> Melee Weapon Attack: your spell attack modifier to hit, reach 5 ft., one target you can see. Hit: 1d8 + PB force damage.

**Artificer's Enhanced Arcane Focus Infusion** Tasha's Cauldron of Everything (pg. 21):

> While holding this item, a creature gains a + 1 bonus to spell attack rolls. In addition, the creature ignores half cover when making a spell attack.
> The bonus increases to +2 when you reach 10th level in this class.

**All-Purpose Tool** Tasha's Cauldron of Everything (pg. 119):

> Wondrous item, uncommon (+1), rare (+2), very rare (+3) (requires attunement by an artificer)
>
> While holding this tool, you gain a bonus to the spell attack rolls and the saving throw DCs of your artificer spells. The bonus is determined by the tool's rarity.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Comment: Related: [Does Wand of the War Mage improve the accuracy of summons from Tasha's Cauldron of Everything?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/190648/33569)

Answer (score 5):

#### No, the Steel Defender does not benefit from these bonuses.

All-Purpose Tool states:

> While holding this tool, you gain a bonus to the spell attack rolls and the saving throw DCs *of your artificer spells*

The All-Purpose Tool only increase your spell attack modifier when you are casting an artificer spell.

Enhanced Arcane Focus Infusion states:

> *While holding this item, a creature* gains a +1 bonus to *spell attack rolls*.

This infusion adds +1 to your spell attack rolls, but the Steel Defender is an entirely different creature that is not making spell attack rolls.

Both of these items increase your bonus to hit, *but only under certain circumstances*. The Steel Defender's bonus to hit is equal to your spell attack modifier *at the time it is making the attack*, and at this time your spell attack bonus is unmodified by the All-Purpose Tool and Enhanced Arcane Focus Infusion.

Answer (score 1):

### The *all-purpose tool* definitely doesn't work.

Since the tool only grants a bonus to the spell attack rolls "of your artificer spells", and your Steel Defender's melee attack is not an artificer spell, it definitely doesn't apply.

### The Enhanced Arcane Focus infusion might work.

Since the enhanced focus infusion says "while holding this item, a creature gains a +1 bonus to spell attack rolls" and the creature holding it is you, it probably doesn't work, but on the other hand it's a generic bonus to the stat that the Steel Defender uses for its attack rolls, so it's hard to say no.

In general, I tend to lean in favor of the players when a question like this comes up, and if it's just a +1, I'm not too terribly concerned about the balance implications, so I'd be inclined to allow it.

I don't know if a steel defender can 'hold' an item to gain the bonus itself, if you decided to got that direction, but it sounds like that isn't the question at hand anyway.