# If a spell is stored in a Ring of Spell Storing, and then the original caster's save DC/attack bonus changes, which save DC/attack bonus do I use?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, spellcasting, difficulty-class

For the [*ring of spell storing*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/ring-of-spell-storing), I know a stored spell's save DC/attack bonus is based on the caster who originally stored the spell in the ring.

But say the original caster uses temporary items to boost their spell save DC/spell attack bonus (such as a [*bloodwell vial*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/bloodwell-vial)) after they've stored a spell in the ring. If the stored spell is then cast from the *ring of spell storing*, which version of the original caster's spell save DC/attack bonus is used?

- Is it the spell DC/attack bonus of the caster at the time the spell
  was stored?
- Or is it the caster's current spell DC/attack bonus (i.e. at the time
  the stored spell is cast from the ring)?

---

Another similar situation:

Say I cast a spell into the *ring of spell storing*. I then level up and my proficiency bonus increases.
If the stored spell is then cast from the ring, does it use the spell save DC/attack bonus from before I level up (i.e. when it was stored in the ring)? Or the new values after I level up?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] or visit the [help] to get some guidance about posting questions and answers! Just a quick remark: the *bloodwell vial* is an item for sorcerers; is your character a sorcerer?

Comment: Related: [Do the relevant stats of a creature summoned via a "Summon Creature Type"-style spell change, if your stats change after you summoned it?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/194823/23547)

Comment: Related: [Does wand of the war mage improve the accuracy of the creatures summoned from Tasha's cauldren?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/190648/does-wand-of-the-war-mage-improve-the-accuracy-of-summons-from-tashas-cauldron), [Is the steel defenders force empowered rend affected by items that add +1 to spell attack rolls?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/190594/is-the-steel-defenders-force-empowered-rend-affected-by-items-that-add-1-to-sp)

Answer (score 13):

The description of the [*ring of spell storing*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/ring-of-spell-storing) magic item states:

> While wearing this ring, you can cast any spell stored in it. The
> spell uses the slot level, spell save DC, spell attack bonus, and
> spellcasting ability of the original caster, but is otherwise treated
> as if you cast the spell.

While the description makes no mention of the current or past state of the spellcaster, consider what happens when you rule that it's based on the *current* state of the spellcaster:

- Someone casts a spell into the *ring of spell storing*, and then later on you get your hands on it.
- It turns out the caster was later hit by a [*feeblemind*](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/feeblemind) spell (and their ability score dropped to 1)
- Or they died.

You wouldn't tack on a -4 (or whatever the minus is for a dead spellcaster) just because the original caster's current spell attack bonus (or spell save DC) is different.

From this, I don't think it's unreasonable to say the spell save DC/attack bonus should be based on whatever the caster's was when the spell was stored in the ring.

**Important note:** This doesn't stack with other spells or abilities that grant a bonus to attack rolls or give advantage, because all of those require an attack roll – which is *not* part of putting the spell into the ring.

The vial would work because it grants a bonus to the spell save DC, *not to the attack roll*.

And as a counter-example, you couldn't store a spell with extra Bardic Inspiration stored with it, because Bardic Inspiration is a bonus to an attack roll – not to the act of storing the spell, which doesn't involve an attack.